# Does anyone know how to troubleshoot a Worklight SQL adapter?

Tags: sql, adapter, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm a newbie to Worklight. I have imported module 6.1 from the developerWorks getting started with Worklight sample http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started/

I am getting the error in the error as configured in the javascript 
"Can't get cities list. Check database connection"

Does anyone know how to troubleshoot? The connection parameters in "SQLAdapter.xml" are very straight forward.

Comment: Have you also followed the steps starting from page 20 in the training module PPT? Namely, execute the .sql file in order to create the cities backend, otherwise the adapter request to the database will fail...

Comment: Hi Idan, continuing with this thread... Yes, I did follow the steps but I am still getting the error from the Worklight project javascript "Can't get cities list. Check database connection". Other than that I do not see any errors in the Eclipse console. So where do I go from here to debug? I believe MySQL DB is set correctly. Only difference is that I changed the user and password in "SQLAdapter.xml" to be root:root since I did not know how to create the "Worklight" user in MySQL Workbench.

Comment: Try SQLyog, it has a much simpler user interface. Other than that also make to to give either the worklight or root users full permissions on the database after running the .sql script.

Comment: Hi Idan, here is an update. I am seeing this error in the Eclipse console: 

Procedure 'getCitiesWeather' invocation failed. Runtime: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight bundles.java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found in Worklight bundles.

I thought I had the right driver in the project Server/lib folder, it is named ojdbc5.jar. Let me know if I did this step wrong.

Comment: You may check this link http://javatechig.com/2013/03/18/how-to-create-a-sql-adapter-in-ibm-worklight/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Worklight MySQL adapter request to reach the MySQL database, you need to add the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar to your project.

You can download the MySQL Connector/J file via this URL: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Choose "platform Independent" in the dropdown, and click the Download button for the .zip option.
Uncompress the .zip file and copy the mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar to yourProject\server\lib.

Comment: Hi Idan, I got the SQLAdapter Working!!! But Now I've got another error. Seems the HTTPAdapter returns the XML but right after that I get this error, and ideas?

An error occurred while invoking procedure HTTPWeather/HttpRequestFWLSE0100E:  parameters:{
   "arr": [
      {
         "method": "get",
         "parameters": {
            "u": "c",
            "w": "2459115"
         },
         "path": "forecastrss",
         "returnedContentType": "xml"
      }
   ]
}
org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class

Comment: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser
FWLSE0101E: Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: SAX2 driver class org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser not found
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser

Comment: Add the following line (minus quote signs) in Eclipse's startup configuration file, eclipse.ini (can be found in your Eclipse's directory): "
-Dorg.xml.sax.driver = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser"

Comment: Modified eclipse.ini, restarted Eclipse, but got the same error. Here are the contents on my eclipse.ini file:

-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.100.v20110502
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dworklight.port=8085
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
-Dorg.xml.sax.driver = com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.SAXParser

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Seems there was a problem with my Eclipse install, or Java on Windows. So I switched back to causing my Eclipse and Java installed on IOS and all is working. Also, the IBM documentation was unclear, but now that I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar in my  Project\server\lib folder.